# Deactivate manually a virtual environment activated by direnv without leaving the project directory or shell

Tags: python, python-venv, python-poetry, direnv

This is my first approach to direnv. I've been trying to adapt direnv to Poetry and venv.

~/.zshrc:

```
# skip loading direnv if it is already loaded
if test -z $DIRENV_DIR; then
    if whereis direnv 2&>1 1> /dev/null ; then
        case "$(basename $SHELL)" in
            zsh)
                eval "$(direnv hook zsh)"
                ;;
            bash)
                eval "$(direnv hook bash)"
                ;;
            *)
                echo "skip" /dev/null
                ;;
        esac
    fi
fi
# substitute prompt (direnv)
setopt PROMPT_SUBST

show_virtual_env() {
  if [[ -n "$VIRTUAL_ENV" && -n "$DIRENV_DIR" ]]; then
    echo "($(basename $VIRTUAL_ENV)) "
  fi
}
PS1='$(show_virtual_env)'$PS1
```

~/.config/direnv/direnvrc:

```
layout_poetry() {
    PYPROJECT_TOML="${PYPROJECT_TOML:-pyproject.toml}"
    if [[ ! -f "$PYPROJECT_TOML" ]]; then
        log_status "No pyproject.toml found. Executing \`poetry init\` to create a \`$PYPROJECT_TOML\` first."
        poetry init
    fi

    if [[ -d ".venv" ]]; then
        VIRTUAL_ENV="$(pwd)/.venv"
    else
        VIRTUAL_ENV=$(poetry env info --path 2>/dev/null ; true)
    fi

    if [[ -z $VIRTUAL_ENV || ! -d $VIRTUAL_ENV ]]; then
        log_status "No virtual environment exists. Executing \`poetry install\` to create one."
        poetry install
        VIRTUAL_ENV=$(poetry env info --path)
    fi

    PATH_add "$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin"
    export POETRY_ACTIVE=1
    export VIRTUAL_ENV
}
```

Everything works, but there's no way to deactivate the virtual environment.

.envrc with Poetry:

```
layout poetry
```

.envrc with (`python -m venv .venv`):

```
layout python
```

In both cases, `C-d` or `exit` exits the shell, and `deactivate` is unavailable, which is somewhat unexpected in the latter case. What can I do to deactivate the virtual environment and stay within the same directory? And to get back into the virtual environment the same way, for that matter.